# How to strip simple sentence, strip up to third full stop?

Tags: php

I have a long string of text, how can I limit the output to count the full stops and just output say up to the third full stop?

**Ex Raw:**

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

**Desired Output**

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

```
 // Long text
 $profile_desc = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.';

 // Split long text on each full stop.
 $profile_desc_out = explode( '. ', $profile_desc );

 $i = 0;
 // Repeat 3 times to get three sentences 
 foreach( $profile_desc_out as $profile_desc_output ){
   echo $profile_desc_output;
   if( ++$i > 3 ) {
     break;
   }
 }
 // How to incorporate implode() function to put back together?
```

Comment: Split (explode) string on stops. Get first three items. Put back together (implode).

Comment: thanks @GolezTrol, I have done what you recommend but I do not understand how to use implode() in this context?

Comment: `implode` does the reverse of `explode`. This would be useful if you want the three sentences to be merged together in one string. But since you echo the text right away there is no need for that.

Comment: PS. For this case, the classic loop might be easier: `for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { echo $profile_desc_out[$i]; }`.

Comment: Thanks. I did want to put the the three sentences back together into a sting . If I echo it out without imploding, it strips the full stop and preceding space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, `RegExp` comes to the rescue :)

The `3` is the maximum number of sentences to display. The `1` is the minimum count.

```
// Long text
$profile_desc = "This paragraph. Has. More. Than three. Sentences.";

preg_match('#^(?:[^\.]+\.){1,3}#', $profile_desc, $matches);
echo $matches[0], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
This paragraph. Has. More.
```

Comment: Wow that seems more elegant and less lines. I'll test this out. Thank you.